# Attempted to call an undefined method named "getRequest" of class . Sendind e-mail in SwiftMailer Symfony

Tags: php, email, symfony, swiftmailer

I'm trying to sen an e-mail by SwiftMailer in Symfony 3. I'm going through that tutorial: http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/validators-and-forms.html#sending-the-email and I've got the problem in "Creating the form in the controller" : "Attempted to call an undefined method named "getRequest" of class "AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController". "

That's my contactAction() in src/AppBundle/DeffaultController:

```
/**
 * @Route("/contact"), name="cont")
 */
public function contactAction()
{

    $enquiry = new Enquiry();
    $form = $this->createForm(EnquiryType::class, $enquiry);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // Perform some action, such as sending an email

            // Redirect - This is important to prevent users re-posting
            // the form if they refresh the page
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('app_default_contact'));
        }
    }


    return $this->render(':default:contact.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Help please!

Comment: Are you file and class names the same, and is the namespace set correctly? And is your class extending the root controller giving you access to the methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getRequest` was a method of the `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` base class.  It was deprecated since version 2.4 and it's been removed in 3.0.

To get it in your controller, just add it as an argument and type-hint it with the Request class:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function contactAction(Request $request)
{

    // ...
```

Documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#the-request-object-as-a-controller-argument).

Comment: Could you tell me what should I change  in code becouse i really don't know. :(

Comment: How to change that line? $request = $this->getRequest();

Comment: is my answer so bad to be incomprehensible? just remove `$request = $this->getRequest();` and add the type-hint it with the Request class as a written above

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry for my "not understanding" but I'm new in it. It works! :)

Answer (score 1):

the function getRequest() is deprecated and removed after symfony-3 and later. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller; is still used and maintained in current (4.03) version.   github.com/symfony/framework-bundle

to get the request:

```
$request = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `getRequest` use `$request`....