# Attempted to call an undefined method named "getRequest" of class "AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController"

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, symfony

I want to make login and logout through session. but I am getting error.

> "Attempted to call an undefined method named "getRequest" of class
>   "AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController".

This is my **DefaultController.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use AppBundle\Entity\users;
use AppBundle\Entity\Login;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;



class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */

    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {

        $session=$this->getRequest()->getSession();
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $repository=$em->getRepository('AppBundle:users');


        if($request->getMethod()=='POST')
        {

        $session->clear();
        $username=$request->get('username');
        $password=$request->get('password');
        $remember=$request->get('remember');





        $user=$repository->findOneBy(array('userName'=>$username, 'password'=>$password)); 



        if($user)
        {
            if($remember=='remember-me')
            {
                $login=new Login();
                $login->setUserName($username);
                $login->setPassword($password);
                $session->set('login', $login);
            }
            return $this->render('default/welcome.html.twig', array('name' =>$user->getFirstName()));

        }
        else
            {
            return $this->render('default/login.html.twig', array('name' => 'Login Error'));
        }
    }
    else{

        if($session->has('login'))
        {
            $login=$session->get('login');
            $username=$login->getUserName();
            $password=$login->getPassword();
            $user=$repository->findOneBy(array('userName'=>$username, 'password'=>$password));

    if($user)
        {   
    return $this->render('default/welcome.html.twig', array('name' =>$user->getFirstName()));
        }       

        }

        return $this->render('default/login.html.twig');
    } 
    }



    /**
     * @Route("/signupe", name="signupe")
     */

    public function signupeAction(Request $request)
    {
            if($request->getMethod()=='POST'){

                $username=$request->get('username');
                $firstname=$request->get('firstname');
                $password=$request->get('password');

                $user = new Users();
                $user->setFirstName($firstname);
                $user->setPassword($password);
                $user->setUserName($username);
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();



    }   

    return $this->render('default/signupe.html.twig');

}

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
     */

    public function logoutAction(Request $request)
    {
    $session=$this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $session->clear();
    return $this->render('default/login.html.twig');
    }

}
```

**login.html.twig**

```
<html>
<head>
{% block stylesheets %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('templates/css/1.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('templates/css/parsley.css') }}">
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}

<script src="{{ asset('templates/js/parsley.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('templates/js/parsley.extend.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('templates/js/parsley-standalone.min.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>


{% block container %}

<div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Login User</h2>                    
        <form class="form-sigin" method="POST" action="{{path('login')}}" data-validate="parsley">
        <div><input type="text" name="username" class="txtbox" placeholder="Email Address"  data-trigger="change"  data-required="true" data-type="email"></div>
        <div><input type="password" name="password" class="txtbox" placeholder="Password" data-trigger="change" data-required="true"></div>
        <div>
        <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"><span>Remember Me</span></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Log In" class="loginBtn"></div>
        <div><span><a href="">Forgot Password</a></span></div>






        </form>
    </div>
    {% if name is defined  %}
    <div class="alert-info fade in">
    <strong>How are you</strong>
    </div>
    {% endif  %}
    {% endblock %}  
    </body>
    </html>
```

**signupe.html.twig**

```
    {% block stylesheet  %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('templates/css/1.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('templates/css/parsley.css') }}">

    <style>
form {
    border: 0px solid #f1f1f1;
}

input[type=text]{
    /* width: 100%; */
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=password] {
    /* width: 100%; */
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 11px 22px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align:center;
    /* width: 100%; */
}

.Btn {
    margin-left: 50px;
    }

button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.cancelbtn {
    width: auto;
    padding: 11px 18px;
    background-color: #f44336;
}

.imgcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}

img.avatar {
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
    padding: 16px;
    text-align:center;
}

span.psw {
    float: center;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    span.psw {
       display: block;
       float: none;
    }
    .cancelbtn {
       width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>

    {% endblock %}


    {% block javascripts %}

<script src="{{ asset('templates/js/parsley.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('templates/js/parsley.extend.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('templates/js/parsley-standalone.min.js') }}"></script>

    {% endblock %}


    {% block container  %}

    <h2 align="center">Sign Up</h2>
    <form method="POST" action="{{path('signupe') }}" data-validate="parsley">
    <div class="container">
    <label><b>User Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter User Name" name="username" placeholder="Email Address"  data-trigger="change"  data-required="true" data-type="email">
    <br>

    <label><b>Repeat User Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" id="usernameRe" placeholder="Enter User Name" name="usernameRe" placeholder="Email Address"  data-trigger="change"  data-required="true" data-type="email" data-equalto="#username">
    <br>

    <label><b>First Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstname" placeholder="Email Address"  data-trigger="change"  data-required="true">
    <br>


    <label><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" placeholder="Email Address"  data-trigger="change"  data-required="true"><br>
    <div class="Btn">   
    <button type="submit">Create Account</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>


        {% endblock %}
```

**welcome.html.twig**

```
   {%block container %}
<div class="container">
    <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

</div> 
<a href="{{path('logout')}}">Logout</a>
    {%endblock%}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/40KxK.jpg
```

Comment: Try $request->getSession(); Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempted to call an undefined method named "getRequest" of class . Sendind e-mail in SwiftMailer Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981191/attempted-to-call-an-undefined-method-named-getrequest-of-class-sendind-e-ma)

Comment: sir after replaced this i am getting 'FatalThrowableError Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$em' (T_VARIABLE)' error

Comment: Above error has been solve, but i am getting Notice: Undefined variable: session on line number 184

Comment: Whatever tutorial you happen to be using, toss it away.  Follow the examples in the manual to get started.

Comment: Sir I sloved above error also but my session give me null value, how can i get name other values from it

Answer (score 2):

`getRequest()` method in Symfony controller has been deprecated since version 2.4, and was removed in 3.0. You're already injecting the `$request` object, so just use `$request->getSession()`.

Comment: sir after replaced this i am getting 'FatalThrowableError
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$em' (T_VARIABLE)' error

Comment: Sir Above error has been solve, but i am getting Notice: Undefined variable: session on line number 184

Comment: That's a different kind of error. Just make sure that `$session` variable is defined in that scope. I don't know how line 184 and its surroundings look like anyway.